# anydbm module, values() , items() method doesn't work

Tags: python, database

Currently, I am studying [Think python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/) and I had problem with chapter 14.6, database module: **anydbm**. Even thought the book said I can use 
`keys()` method and `items()` method as a *dictionary*, I wasn't able to use `items()` method.
so I checked the [python document](http://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html). It said I can use 
`iteritems()` and `values()` too. However I wasn't able to use both of them.
(I could use `keys()` method)

these are the error I got:

```
>>> import anydbm
>>> db = anydbm.open('cache2','c')
>>> db['www.python.org'] = 'python website'
>>> db['www.cnn.com'] = 'cable news network'

>>> for k,v in db.iteritems():
...     print k,'\t',v
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: iteritems

>>> for v in db.values():
...     print v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: values
```

Also, In the book, He said we can use for statement, but I couldn't use it.

I don't know what is wrong. I am using python 2.7.2 and Mac OS x
Thank you

Comment: What do you get when you execute type(db) and dir(db)?

Comment: I got this: so it means, I cannot use iteritems and values.
`>>> type(db)
<type 'dbm.dbm'>
>>> dir(db)
['close', 'get', 'has_key', 'keys', 'setdefault']
`

Comment: I don't think that’s the problem. In older version everything works and you see the same examples in 2.7.2 docs http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/anydbm.html?highlight=anydb#module-anydbm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work although it is not the real solution:

```
import anydbm
db = anydbm.open('cache2','c')
db['www.python.org'] = 'python website'
db['www.cnn.com'] = 'cable news network'

for key in db.keys():
    print key, db[key]
```

Comment: Definitely root of the problem is what you get from anydbm.open('cache2','c'). In case of 2.6 and 2.7.5 where everything works I actually get bsddb._DBWithCursor not dbm.dbm.

Comment: Yep. You should read that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650914/basic-anydbm-example-generates-attributeerror-iteritems

Comment: I understood Apple-supplied python doesn't support any third-party database, but still I don't know how to solve that problem. 
I'm sorry again to ask, Would you please tell me what I should do to solve this problem? 
I think I should use different python module(not default one), but don't know how

Comment: For Python 3.3 there is a patch available here http://bugs.python.org/issue9523. You could always try to modify it to work with 2.7. But I would say it is not really worth you time. Interface of dbm.dbm is a little bit different, but for learning purpose you can easy emulate full dictionary interface using .keys() and attribute access methods.